# Need command or script to fetch only specific lines from a paragraph in a file in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

Need command or script to fetch only specific paragraph from a file in Unix/Linux

Files formatting is like

```
=================================
THREAD NUMBER
MESSAGE NUMBER
Severity
File_LOCATION
FUNCTION_NAME
LINE_NUMBER
TIME STAMP
BLANK LINE
SINGLE LINE ERROR TEXT
=================================
```

Here i Want to extract only severity and message text part for user input severity.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  What is your question?  (No, "I need to" is not a question, and just "How do I do this?" would not meet the criteria of Stackoverflow — here you should demonstrate your own efforts so we can answer a narrow question or two.)  Is the text you wrote verbatim or symbolic?  Could you post a verbatim version (if it is symbolic)?

Comment: I was using the Below from my side :-

grep -A 6 "Severity: $1" <file_name> >> out.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk "/Severity: $1/,/File_LOCATION/" < file_name > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `cat file | tail --lines=+3 | head -1` to get the third line out of the given file.  But I  don't know if this is what you want or need.

Comment: The file has multiple paragraphs of the above format, I just need severity part and message text part.

I was using the grep command to fetch but all i could fetch was all the six lines starting from the pattern

grep -A 6 "Severity: $1" file_name >> out.txt